# How to change the position of two y variables in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, bar-chart, reshape

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    df <- df_form()
    df <- data.frame(df,options = list(scrollX = TRUE)) 
    df$DemandCharge <- as.numeric(gsub('[$,]','', df$DemandCharge))
    df$NewDemandCharge <- as.numeric(gsub('[$,]','', df$NewDemandCharge))
    df$SavedDemandCharge<- df$DemandCharge-df$NewDemandCharge
    df$month <- format(as.Date(df$Startdate), "%Y-%m")
    mydata<-melt(df,id= c("month","Startdate","Enddate","DemandCharge", "Season"))
    ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = month, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")
})
```

[image]

I am so confused how to change the position of two y in ggplot. How can "NewDemandCharge" and "SavedDemandCharge" switch their position in the chart?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually reorder the levels of a factor with `fct_relevel()` from the `forcats` package. Try:

```
library(forcats)
mydata$variable <- fct_relevel(mydata$variable, "SavedDemandCharge")
```

This should put `"SavedDemandCharge"` in the first position. Can't test it without a reproducible example though.